# How do I link to a collection in rails_admin instead of individual items in a belongs_to?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-admin, ruby-on-rails-6.1

I have a company that has many clients. By default when looking at the Companies tab, I have a field with Clients. Each client has his own separate link to a show page. I'm trying to wire it up so that I don't see each individual client as a link on the company show page, but instead a general link to 'Clients' index that belong to that company.

Here's the Company model

```
has_many :clients, class_name: 'Client', primary_key: 'friendlyName', foreign_key: 'shortname'
```

Here's the Client model

```
belongs_to :company, class_name: 'Company', foreign_key: 'shortname', primary_key: 'friendlyName'
```

The relationship seems to be set up correctly.

Here's what I've tried in rails_admin

```
  config.model 'Company' do
    exclude_fields :created_at, :updated_at
    object_label_method do
      :custom_label_method
    end
    
    list do
      field :all_clients do
        formatted_value do
          path = bindings[:view].index_path(model_name: 'Client', all_clients: bindings[:object].id)
          bindings[:view].link_to('Clients', path)
        end
      end
    end
  end
```

That's a code snippet that I've found and it does work to create a custom link to the Clients index page, but it doesn't take the belongs_to association into account.

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track, you need the link to be built as RailsAdmin does it when filtering Client records in the index view by company. You need to do it manually once to figure out how the link is built.
In an image this is what i mean

[image]

I added a filter and look at the url rails admin built.

Make sure you have the Client index config has the company field to be able to do it.

```
class Client < ApplicationRecord
  rails_admin do
    list do
      field :company do
        filterable true
      end
    end
  end
end
```